# Is it possible to get a permanent download link via Vimeo API

Tags: download, vimeo, permanent

I've been trying to get download URLs for some videos I own on Vimeo. The website UI gives permanent URLs, but I haven't found a way to get them via API. The blog posts I've seen suggests API only provides links with 24 hours expiration date.

Instead I'm using links with expiration date but it is not optimal. Any ideas to get permanent links would be much appreciated, thanks.